# Relationships for a Magazine Database

Tags: database-design

I am building a database/web app so that I can quickly search ~1000 magazine issues for articles (though immaterial, they have all been scanned into PDFs). I am doing this as a project for my own education and it may be a bit ambitious for my first, but I'm willing to try it (and my planned second project is even more ambitious).

The magazines in question are guitar titles. Most have the sheet music (tablature) for multiple songs included which is why I am interested in keeping them. Many also have 1-2 page lessons from a variety of players. My collection of magazines goes back well into the '80s but has significant gaps in dates (also immaterial).

My first pass at basic relationships looks like the following:

- Magazine --> Date (1 magazine title has multiple issue dates, like String Wanker 2014 Aug)
- Date --> Magazine (1 month/year may have multiple magazines released, but who cares? Right? Why search for all mags released in August of 2014?)
- Magazine --> Artist (1 magazine month/year has multiple artists, like Sulphurica or Y'all Also)
- Magazine --> Tablatures (1 magazine month/year may have multiple tablatures, Song01 Song02 etc.)
- Magazine --> Lessons (1 magazine month/year may have multiple lessons, Column01 Column02 etc.)
- Artist --> Magazine (1 artist may be in multiple magazines, Wheedly Wizards 2012 Sep and WW 2013 Jan)
- Tablatures --> Magazine (1 tab/song may be in multiple magazines, Pickin' It 1999 Mar and PI 2000 Jun)
- Instructor --> Magazine (1 lesson series from 1 instructor runs across multiple issues of 1 magazine)

I have gotten this far, but I'm very unsure about the relationships (1:1, M:1, 1:N, M:N). I can't come up with a "certain" answer for many of these and I'm getting bogged down. I want this to be flexible, but decisions must be made!

Thank you kindly, in advance, for any assistance/guidance you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you have too many links to the 'magazine' table. Such a table should have probably only three fields: an id number, its name and date.

Your primary table would be 'articles': this table would have an id, a link to its parent magazine issue, a title, page number, an author and possibly flag fields, such as 'contains tablature', etc.

Using a link table to join artists to articles means that an artist can appear in more than one article, and an article may be about more than one artist. Some articles may be not about any artist and so won't appear in this link table.

If, as you say, an article may contain more than one tab, then you might need a table 'tabs': parent article, name, etc. Such a table would be needed only if you want to access tabs directly; it may be enough to have the article's "contains tablature" flag set.